# Telerik skin property not working

Tags: webforms, telerik

I am trying to assign skin to the radwizard using Skin property of the Telerik in a web forms asp.net but somehow only default is working and no other skin are working I tried changing dlls and also there are no errors. i tried adding the RadSkinManager and selected a skin from there but only default works others doesn't render. I have EnableEmbeddedSkins set as false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use one of the pre-packaged Telerik skins, you need to set

```
EnableEmbeddedSkins="true"
```

either globally or in your specific control.

I believe this is your problem.